# Jquery Ajax click button dont send data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my code for Javascript Ajax Jquery send data do purchase item.

```
    $('.reserve-button').click(function(e){

          var book_id = $(this).parent().data('id');

  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
       url: "/php/insertpurchase.php",
       type: "POST",//type of posting the data
        data: {"bookID": book_id},
       success: function (data) {
            alertify.alert("This item was add to your cart.", function(){
    alertify.message('OK');
  });
       },
       error: function (result, status, err) {
       console.log('error', err, status);
    },
       timeout : 15000//timeout of the ajax call
  });

});
```

This is HTML code for submit.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <?php $bookID = $row['id'];?>
            <div class= "obutton feature2" data-id="<?php echo $bookID;?>">
    <button class="reserve-button"><?php echo $row['price'];?></button>
```

In PHP dont receive POST value ->

```
if(isset($_POST['bookID']))
{
 $idProduct = $_POST['bookID'];
```

Comment: And there's no errors, the ajax call alerts OK and everything seems fine ?

Comment: @adeneo if it sucess will show the script alertify... and btw dont receive any value in php server....

Comment: So it is successful, is that what you're saying, you get the `OK` alert, but nothing on the server

Comment: @adeneo i dont receive anything in the client-side...

Comment: The question is really simple, when you run your code, do you see an alert saying `OK` or not?  If not, do you see the console.log with the error? If none of them, the request times out, probably because you never echo anything back

Comment: @adeneo not, dont receive alert... and console log dont show me any error...

Comment: In your PHP, add a line that says `echo "I ALWAYS NEED TO RETURN SOMETHING";` and see what happens

Comment: You did of course check that the click handler really fires when you click

Comment: @adeneo i have try in postman and works the server side, dont works the client-side

Comment: click dont fires when i clicked...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to define this code:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Replace of this code:

```
success: function (data) {
    alertify.alert("This item was add to your cart.", function(){
    alertify.message('OK');
});
```

Now you see what result you get in the console.